# How to configure a common Python environment for several containers in a docker-compose file?

Tags: python, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook, airflow, jupyter

I'm currently writing a docker-compose file with several containers, including Airflow and Jupyter. Eventually, I would like to use Airflow to run a Python script and a Jupyter Notebook. However, dependencies that I installed for the Jupyter container are not available for the Airflow container as they have their own Python environments. How would one go about creating a common Python environment so that dependencies installed during development in Jupyter are also available for Airflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place all the requirements in a `requirements.txt` file in the repository and then use the `Dockerfile` to install them while doing the build of the image. Example commands (assumes `requirements.txt` is in the same folder as the `Dockerfile`):

```
COPY requirements.txt ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}/requirements.txt
```

I've never ran a Jupyter Notebook using Airflow, but seems that [Papermill](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-papermill/stable/operators.html) does the trick.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I was planning on using Papermill. Following your solution, wouldn't all the requirements need to be installed each time the container is restarted? I would like to persist the dependencies.

Comment: I'm not a Docker expert, but from my knowledge it just install that whenever you build your images. When the container is restarted you just pull the image that you already have (don't install that again).